# Is delayed_job async?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asynchronous, delayed-job

I'm try to run long task asyncroniously.
But a task runned syncroniously. Is a delayed job 3.0.5 can run job's async?

I'd try:
model:

```
MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  def do_something
    sleep 10
  end
  #handle_asynchronously :do_something

end
```

and i call it from controller:

```
def do_it
  new_do = MyModel.new id: 1
  new_do.delay.do_something
  render json: {"status":"200"}
end
```

after get request i'm still waiting 10 seconds before response given.
So, where i was wrong and what can i do to run it and receive response from controller before 10 seconds?

Comment: you might have a misspelling in your action `do it` with the variable `new_so`.

Comment: You shouldn't use `delay` and `handle_asynchronously` together, the one excludes the other

Comment: I comment thhis later by @rdlh comment

Answer (score 0):

You **should NOT** use `handle_asynchronously` with `delay`. Use just one of them, not both in the same time.

If your method should always be run in the background, prefer `#handle_asynchronously`.

[Documentation here](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job)

Comment: Yes, i try without 'handle_asynchronously'. Nothing else. Application and workers restarted, but job runned syncroniously anyway. Also i'd tryed with 'handle_asynchronously' and without '.delay'. Sync anyway ALL DAY! ^)

Comment: I'm use the script call RAILS_ENV=development script/delayed_job restart and manual deletind delayed_job records from DB. So, I restarted the puma and nginx and server. Nothing help me.